# Using darkreader package in Angular

Tags: angular

How to use DarkReader in Angular?

I was trying to import DarkReader from this npm package. However, always got error **isEnabled** not defined.

```
    import {
    enable as enableDarkMode,
    disable as disableDarkMode,
    auto as followSystemColorScheme,
    exportGeneratedCSS as collectCSS,
    isEnabled as isDarkReaderEnabled
} from 'darkreader';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been fixed in module's current version: "4.9.28", but in NPM registry, the version is still "4.9.27".

A quick workaround is simply to import this outside the scope, like so:

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HelloComponent } from "./hello.component";

import {
  enable as enableDarkMode,
  disable as disableDarkMode,
  auto as followSystemColorScheme,
  exportGeneratedCSS as collectCSS,
} from "darkreader";

import isEnabled from "darkreader"; // notice this import

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `isEnabled` type is missing in the exports, that is the reason it is throwing error.

But you can still use it by changing its type to `any`.

```
import * as DarkReader from "darkreader";

darkReader: any = DarkReader;

this.darkReader.enable({
      brightness: 100,
      contrast: 90,
      sepia: 10
});

console.log(this.darkReader.isEnabled()); //true
```

[Example Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dark-reader?file=src/app/app.component.ts)